# jQuery IE8 not working however IE7, IE6 and others work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Im trying to get jQuery to run in IE8 so i created the example to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test jQuery</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

      $("body").css("background", "red");

  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in IE6, IE7 and IE9+ however just does not work in IE8, Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to use latest jQuery 1.x.y?

Comment: more info? example any error you hit etc

Comment: There is no CSS code, this is the full HTML.

Comment: You need to add `!important`

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery css official documentation I found:

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, **background**,
>   border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.
>   For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered border-width, use:
>   $( elem ).css( "borderTopWidth" ), $( elem ).css( "borderBottomWidth"
>   ), and so on.
>
> Blockquote

try `$("body").css( "background-color","red" )` and $`("body").css( "backgroundColor","red" )`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is just an example i cannot get jQuery to even work with .click() in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Here, mainly you need to add `!important`

Add `background-color: red !important;` as say for example `_bgcolor` class in css and add that css `_bgcolor` class in javascript as following:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

      $("body").addClass('_bgcolor');

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add"http:" before the url start.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not required as // takes care of if the page is an HTTPS or HTTP connection.

Comment: Some browsers, require to include http